# Spring and Progress-4GL - Change JPA schema naming query format

Tags: sql, spring, openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I have a Spring Boot Application which connects to a Progress Open Edge Database (NOT postgree).

But I am having some issues when trying to get data from Progress Table, it returns the following error when I call methods such "findAll()" or "findById()":

```
Table/view/synonynm "EMS2ESP.INTEG_TABLE_003C" cannot be found. (15814) (-210083)
```

But, "INTEG_TABLE_003C" does exist in "EMS2ESP" database. When running the select directly it works correctly.

I am trying with the following properties in my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:datadirect:openedge://HOM-DB-01:25475;databaseName=ems2esp
spring.datasource.username=sysprogress
spring.datasource.password=sysprogress
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.OpenEdgeDriver
spring.datasource.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

And this is one of my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INTEG_TABLE_003C")
@Data
public class Progress003c extends IntegTable003c {
 // Class properties and etc...
}
```

I would like to make Spring remove the "EMS2ESP" schema from the generated query because I saw some online posts saying that this could cause the error above.

How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: When you say that "running the select directly works correctly" what did that query look like and what tool did you use to run it "directly"?

Comment: @TomBascom I mean: When I run a select statement like "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INTEG_TABLE003C" using the progress "workbench" it finds the table and returns the value

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that is adding the default PUB schema to your query. I'm just guessing but I suspect that the problem you are having is that you are getting the dbname plugged in instead of the schema name or you need to prefix your table names with PUB. Something like: @Table(name = "PUB.INTEG_TABLE_003C") might do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by doing the following:

1. In "application.properties" I put the following lines

   ```
   spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy

   spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
   ```
2. In the connection string I added ";INITIALIZATIONSTRING=set schema 'PUB'" at the very end. It looks like this now:

   ```
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:datadirect:openedge://HOM-DB-01:25475;databaseName=ems2esp;INITIALIZATIONSTRING=set schema 'PUB'
   ```

Also, I had to ensure that "schema" property in @Table annotation should NOT be defined:

```
@Table(name = "INTEG_TABLE_003C", schema="DO NOT DEFINE SCHEMA")
```